# Unity interface serialization and selection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently acquired the asset Odin Inspector, which is wonderful, and that I though could help with this problem.

I'm implementing a Scenario system in the game, which is represented like a node tree like such :

[image: nodetree]

My implementation may not be the best, but I think it suits what we need :

```
public class ScenarioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ScenarioManager Instance { get; private set; }
    public Scenario CurrentScenario { get; private set; }

    [SerializeField] private Scenario scenario;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;

        // TODO : DEBUG : load accordingly
        LoadScenario(scenario);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        int nextState = CurrentScenario.CurrentState.MoveNext();

        if (nextState == -1) return;

        CurrentScenario.Transition(CurrentScenario.CurrentState.transitions[nextState]);
    }

    private void LoadScenario(Scenario toLoad)
    {
        CurrentScenario = toLoad;
        CurrentScenario.StartScenario();
    }
}
```

```
public class Scenario : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ScenarioState CurrentState { get; private set; }

    [SerializeField] private string scenarioName;

    [SerializeField] private ScenarioState initialState;

    public void LoadState(ScenarioState state)
    {
        CurrentState = state;
        if (CurrentState == null)
        {
            // TODO : scenario end
            Debug.Log("Next state is null : scenario finished or missing transition", this);
            return;
        }

        print($"Entering state '{CurrentState.stateName}'");
    }

    public void Transition(StateTransition transition)
    {
        transition.transitionEvents.Invoke();
        LoadState(transition.state);
    }

    public void StartScenario()
    {
        print($"Starting scenario '{scenarioName}'");
        LoadState(initialState);
    }
}
```

A "state" is a rectangle in my graph

```
public class ScenarioState : SerializedMonoBehaviour
{
    public string stateName;

    public StateTransition[] transitions;

    public int MoveNext()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < transitions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (transitions[i].Condition)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

a "transition" is one arrow

```
[Serializable]
public class StateTransition
{
    public ScenarioState state;

// Here is what I cannot figure out how to do
    [OdinSerialize]
    public ITransitionCondition[] conditions;

    [Serializable] public class TransitionEvents : UnityEvent {}
    public TransitionEvents transitionEvents = new TransitionEvents();

    public bool Condition => CheckCondition();
    private bool CheckCondition()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < conditions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!conditions[i].Condition) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

So, I have an array of ITransitionCondition which is a really basic interface, holding a bool, if every condition in a transition is true, then the transition can occurs.

```
public interface ITransitionCondition
{
    bool Condition { get; }

}
```

Here is a simple condition for exemple, just waiting for a timer :

```
[Serializable]
 public class TransitionConditionTimer : ITransitionCondition
 {
     public bool Condition => TimerCheck();

     [SerializeField] private float timeToWait;
     private float _timer;

     private bool TimerCheck()
     {
         _timer += Time.deltaTime;
         return _timer >= timeToWait;
     }
 }
```

So, what I want to achieve, is have like a dropdown where I can add/remove implementation of ITransitionCondition, but I cannot find a way to do it. 
I'm able to do it using the [ShowInInspector] attribute from Odin, but it is not serialized/saved when I enter/quit play mode or anything. Basically I want the exact same thing but saved.

Here is a simple video showing this :

https://youtu.be/rkf9nS2Mz_0

Everything is fine, but the "conditions" are never saved.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I turned ITransitionCondition to an abstract class :  MonoBehaviour, but I need to create each condition as a gameobject and it's really bad :/

Comment: Interfaces are not serializable, I don't think that Odin can change that.

Comment: However, instead of a MonoBehaviour you could use [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) and create assets you can store like prefabs.

Comment: Yeah but it would be the same, I would need to create one (SO/MB) for each condition, that's really not scalable :/ Maybe it's my implementation that's wrong ? I'd just like to be able to create "conditions" like I'm creating transitions

Comment: hopefully this blog might help but mind that much of it may be out of date https://schemingdeveloper.com/2014/12/04/serializing-delegates-unity/

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks, but I already read this yesterday and I don't think it suits my needs :/ In the meantime, I made some editor tools to automate the creation of the monobehaviour, so I don't lose THAT much time but still... Anyway, the plan for the future is to use GraphView to almost generate everything automatically, I may stick with my hacky workaround until then if I don't find a good solution

Comment: I'm really surprised Odin actually allows you to go that far looking at the video. Have you tried using structs rather than class for the conditions which implement ITransitionCondition ? Maybe Odin will like that better. Or do you have a specific reason to use a class ?

Comment: The only way to serialize an interface or abstract class is to first serialize its concrete type, *then* serialize the object (cast to its concrete type). Most serializers don't do this by default for Very Good Reasons (not limited to being unable to perform the cast). Deserialization would then know what the concrete type was and deserialize it, then (implicitly) cast to the relevant abstract class or interface. I've done this with JsonDotNet, but it requires a custom contract resolver and converter.

Comment: @Vale Yeah, Odin is pretty amazing for a LOT of editor / serialization stuff. So many things possible, I'm slowly learning but it's really great so far. I just wanted to be able to "add" condition the same way I'm doing it with transitions, but I guess it's not that simple. I'll stick with my workaround then, with the editor code / tools I made it's not that much more tedious

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE Yeah, I'll just leave it as is, that just would have been cool to be able to do that (add condition similar to how UnityEvent let you add/remove custom functions)

Comment: @Jichael UnityActions are just `Action<T>`s with some extra magic so that they play nice with the inspector (namely, restricting the number of parameters to 0 or 1). `Action`s are serializable as they're just a method reference and some number of parameters (and serializing those parameters). Unity handles that serialization system for you.